# How can I get current time from YouTube-ios-player-helper on swift?

Tags: swift, current-time

I tried to get current time from YouTube using [YouTube-ios-player-helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper) from swiftUI.
There is `currentTime()` method to call the current time. However, whenever I call this function, it returns `void` value and when I checked the `currentTime()` function, Its return type is actually `void`.
I thought return value should have current time value and it should not be void value. I wonder whether this is wrongly designed function or there is something other. Would you please tell me what's wrong here when I try to get current time from YouTube player?

Below is my swift code

```
struct YTWrapper : UIViewRepresentable {

@Binding var videoID : String
@Binding var seconds : Float

@State var playerView = YTPlayerView()

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> YTPlayerView {
    playerView.load(withVideoId: videoID,
                    playerVars: ["playsinline": 1])
    
    return playerView
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: YTPlayerView, context: Context) {
    
    playerView.seek(toSeconds: seconds, allowSeekAhead: true)
    
    
    @State var temp : Void

    NSLog("current Time:")
    temp = playerView.currentTime()
    print(temp)
    NSLog("end")
}
```

}

and below is the result

```
2021-06-15 20:05:12.086348+0800 Meerkat[3141:795444] current Time:
()
2021-06-15 20:05:12.086446+0800 Meerkat[3141:795444] end
```

Below is the currentTime function from YouTube-ios-player-helper

```
/**
 * Returns the elapsed time in seconds since the video started playing. This
 * method corresponds to the JavaScript API defined here:
 *   https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#getCurrentTime
 *
 * @param completionHandler async callback block that contains float number with the result or an error.
 */
- (void)currentTime:(_Nullable YTFloatCompletionHandler)completionHandler;
```

---

```
- (void)currentTime:(_Nullable YTFloatCompletionHandler)completionHandler {
  [self evaluateJavaScript:@"player.getCurrentTime();"
         completionHandler:^(id  _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (!completionHandler) {
      return;
    }
    if (error) {
      completionHandler(-1, error);
      return;
    }
    if (!result || ![result isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
      completionHandler(0, nil);
      return;
    }
    completionHandler([result floatValue], nil);
  }];
}
```

Comment: currentTime function returns void but there is a completion block that will give the value as you can see from the objective-c code (from Youtube helper) that you shared.

Comment: @ChanpreetSingh would you please elaborate it more? 

you mean '- (void)currentTime:(_Nullable YTFloatCompletionHandler)completionHandler {...}' this part?
Since I'm not familiar with objective-c code, I don't understand quite well the code in YouTube helper. Would you please explain how to use completion block you mentioned to get the current time?
In order to get current time, should I pass some parameter from 'playerView.currentTime()' like 'playerView.currentTime(something)'?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways you can achieve this.
First one is using the currentTime completion handler.

```
ytPlayerView.currentTime { time, error in
    guard let err = error else{
       debugPrint("Elapsed Time:\(time)")
       return
    }
    debugPrint("Error :\(err)")
}
```

I got an issue in the above with evaluating js (youtube helper library issue, maybe need some updating). Give it a try if it work on your side.

OR

Second one is assign delegate to player `ytPlayerView.delegate = self` and make use of the predefined delegate function.

```
func playerView(_ playerView: YTPlayerView, didPlayTime playTime: Float){
      debugPrint("Elapsed Time:\(playTime)")
}
```

Comment: Gotcha! at the first one, I got javascript error at the start of the video. However I don't get any error after playing the video. Also I can get the current time by printing time value. Really thanks !
 *Also tried to apply second methods by studying how to use delegate. however I couldn't apply it by now because I didn't understand fully about how to use that.

Comment: Thanks, but you should definitely read and try delegates because in iOS development you will be using this a lot.

Comment: sure! I will try and learn again. thx ! :)